# Use a JSON array with objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that will get a JSON array with objects. In the function I will be able to loop through the array, access a property and use that property. Like this:

Variable that I will pass to the function will look like this:

```
[{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "Sweden"
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "USA"
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "England"
}]

function test(myJSON) {
  // maybe parse my the JSON variable?
  // and then I want to loop through it and access my IDs and my titles
}
```

Any suggestions how I can solve it?

Comment: the question is not clear. provide more accurate and descriptive code.

Answer (score 72):

This isn't a single JSON object. You have an array of JSON objects. You need to loop over array first and then access each object. Maybe the following kickoff example is helpful:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  "id": 28,
  "Title": "Sweden"
}, {
  "id": 56,
  "Title": "USA"
}, {
  "id": 89,
  "Title": "England"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  var object = arrayOfObjects[i];
  for (var property in object) {
    alert('item ' + i + ': ' + property + '=' + object[property]);
  }
  // If property names are known beforehand, you can also just do e.g.
  // alert(object.id + ',' + object.Title);
}
```

If the array of JSON objects is actually passed in as a plain vanilla string, then you would indeed need `eval()` here.

```
var string = '[{"id":28,"Title":"Sweden"}, {"id":56,"Title":"USA"}, {"id":89,"Title":"England"}]';
var arrayOfObjects = eval(string);
// ...
```

To learn more about JSON, check [MDN web docs: Working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)
.

Comment: Remember `if (object.hasOwnProperty(...`

Comment: +1 for eval() update, wasted so much time not realizing I needed to convert the string into an object.

Comment: @PeadarDoyle: you're welcome. Please make sure that this string doesn't contain user-controlled data, or you may risk JS code injection. But better would be to pass in a fullworthy JS object already from the beginning on. I.e. remove the quotes surrounding the string -if any.

Comment: +1 bra. I was looking  for a way to get Ajax response string to bootstrap multi select. This var arrayOfObjects = eval(string); did the trick

Answer (score 17):

This is your `dataArray`:

```
[
   {
      "id":28,
      "Title":"Sweden"
   },
   {
      "id":56,
      "Title":"USA"
   },
   {
      "id":89,
      "Title":"England"
   }
]
```

Then `parseJson` can be used:

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(dataArray))).each(function() {  
    var ID = this.id;
    var TITLE = this.Title;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

By 'JSON array containing objects' I guess you mean a string containing JSON?

If so you can use the safe `var myArray = JSON.parse(myJSON)` method (either native or included using [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)), or the usafe `var myArray = eval("(" + myJSON + ")")`. eval should normally be avoided, but if you are certain that the content is safe, then there is no problem.

After that you just iterate over the array as normal.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    alert(myArray[i].Title);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question feels a little incomplete, but I think what you're looking for is a way of making your JSON accessible to your code:

if you have the JSON string as above then you'd just need to do this

```
var jsonObj = eval('[{"id":28,"Title":"Sweden"}, {"id":56,"Title":"USA"}, {"id":89,"Title":"England"}]');
```

then you can access these vars with something like jsonObj[0].id etc

Let me know if that's not what you were getting at and I'll try to help.

M

Comment: You shouldn't be using eval() to parse JSON, you know that? Use JSON.parse().

Comment: ^ Because using `eval()` you are more vulnerable since that JS function accepts all JS expressions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

Answer (score 2):

@Swapnil Godambe
It works for me if JSON.stringfy is removed.
That is:

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(dataArray)).each(function() {  
    var ID = this.id;
    var TITLE = this.Title;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var datas = [{"id":28,"Title":"Sweden"}, {"id":56,"Title":"USA"}, {"id":89,"Title":"England"}];
document.writeln("<table border = '1' width = 100 >");
document.writeln("<tr><td>No Id</td><td>Title</td></tr>"); 
for(var i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
document.writeln("<tr><td>"+datas[i].id+"</td><td>"+datas[i].Title+"</td></tr>");
}
document.writeln("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Define a JSON array with objects
var employees = [    {        "name": "John",        "age": 30,        "department": "Sales"    },    {        "name": "Emily",        "age": 28,        "department": "Marketing"    },    {        "name": "Michael",        "age": 35,        "department": "Finance"    }];

// Accessing the objects in the array
console.log(employees[0].name);      // Output: John
console.log(employees[1].age);       // Output: 28
console.log(employees[2].department); // Output: Finance
```

[Json Full Form or What Is Json](https://www.whatisfullform.com/json-full-form/)