# JSON Array Not Decoding With Eval

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, eval

I have two files, one containing an array in PHP that is `echo`ed via json_encode, and the other full of javascript functions for a webpage. One such function, that looks like this (and is unfinished):

```
/*
 * Function: selectVictim
 * Called from function laserOn()
 *
 * Selects a random victim from a list of victims
 *
 * @return String: victim
 */
function selectVictim()
{
var params = "url=queenofsheep.com/Sheep/victims.php";
var request = new ajaxRequest();

request.open("POST", "victims.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            if (this.responseText != null )
            {
                var vicString = this.responseText;
                var vicArray = eval('"'+vicString+'"');
                //var vicArray = vicString.split(',');
                //var numVic = Math.floor(Math.random() * (vicArray - 1));
                alert(vicArray);
            }
            else alert("Ajax error: No data received");
        }
        else alert("Ajax Error: " + this.statusText);
    }
}

request.send(params);
}
```

Is supposed to take in the array from the other file and do things to it that are beyond the scope of this question. Unfortunately, while `this.responseText` contains a JSON encoded array of the format

```
var jsonArr = 
     ["1","2,","3"]
```

activating the function does nothing, and `eval`ing `this.responseText` yields "undefined."

What am I doing wrong here? I can provide more examples of the real code, the actual array, whatever, if need be. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Is your JSON output `var jsonArr = ["1","2,","3"]` or `["1","2,","3"]`?

Comment: Adding quotes around the response text tells it that it's a string.  So there's no result to the eval.  Try wrapping everything in `()` so: `eval('("' + vicString + '")');`.  But realize that adding the quotes will result in nothing more than a string...  Oh, and [Don't eval to parse JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding "(" and ")" to the Eval Function. That's how I've seen it done in the past

```
var myObject = eval('(' + vicString + ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `request` instead of `this`. `this` refers to the `window` object.

Edit: if `var jsonArr=[1, 2, 3];` is literally the response, you should use `eval(vicString+';jsonArr');` if you can't alter the response text.

If you'd run 'eval("var test=[1,2,3];")', you'ld have seen that it indeed returns undefined. But this isn't a good practice in using JSON.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how the handler is called. You can set the value of `this` if you use `fn.apply()` or `fn.call()`. For example `fn.call("something")` sets `this` to the string `"something"`.

Comment: Considering that it alerts, I'm assuming that `this` refers to the request object (otherwise it would never have passed the `if` statements unless window has both `readyState` and `status`)...

Comment: In this case `this` refers to `window`. I didn't say it always does.

Comment: @ircmaxell, he didn't say it's put in those if statements.

Comment: @Lekensteyn. Again, not necessarily :). `request.onreadystatechange.call("something");`. I just set `this` to `"something"`. Without seeing how `ajaxRequest` is implemented, and how the handler is called, there is no way to tell.

Comment: I think Lekensteyn's solution is correct. I'm voting this up.

Comment: What do you mean that he didn't say it's put in those if statements?  Look at the code given.  When `onreadystatechange` is called, it does a bunch of checks against `this.readyState`, `this.status` and `this.responseText`...  Unless `window` has those properties all set (and to valid values), I can't see how the alert could be tripped without `this` being bound to `request`...?

Comment: Whoops, missed "*evaling* this.responseText yields undefined. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type of the response in the server to "application/json" and you won't have to use eval anymore.
Also you would be better of using an ajax framework instead of using your own ajax functions.