# How to parse list item in html to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm to pass an array form php to javascript, my solution is use php to generate an html list items like following:

```
<ul id="data" class="hidden">
  <li value="0"> 
    <ul>
      <li value="id">1</li> 
      <li value="productLine">Vintage Cars</li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li value="1"> 
    <ul>
      <li value="id">2</li> 
      <li value="productLine">Ships</li>    
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li value="2"> 
    <ul>
      <li value="id">3</li> 
      <li value="productLine">Trains</li>   
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and use javascript DOM API to make it to an multidimensional associate array:

```
function selectProductLine(){
    var rootUlNode = document.getElementById('data');
    var rootLiNodes = rootUlNode.children;
    var hiddenHash = {};
    for(var i=0;i< rootLiNodes.length;i++){
        var rootLiNodeValue = rootLiNodes[i].getAttribute('value');     
        var liNodes = rootLiNodes[i].firstElementChild.children;
        for(var i=0; i < liNodes.length;i++){
            hiddenHash[rootLiNodeValue] = {};
            var liNodeValue = liNodes[i].getAttribute('value');
            var liNodeContent = liNodes[i].textContent;
            hiddengegHash[rootLiNodeValue][liNodeValue] = liNodeContent;
        }
    }
return hiddenHash;
}
```

But running the code can crash my browser, so I can't debug it, anyone can point out where my problem is? And I think there should be an element way to transfer data from php to javascript, like using json, could someone provide a better solution or resource on this topic?

Comment: You're using `i` for both loops, that causes some troubles. Use different variable name for inner loop.

Comment: @irrelephant sorry it should be variable hiddenHash, I just intentionally make it wrong, so the browser won't freeze, and I can't debug on that point

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP array, you can use `[json_encode][1]` to render it as a JSON object.  For example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'productLine' => 'Vintage Cars'),
    array('id' => 2, 'productLine' => 'Ships')
);
echo 'var products = ' . json_encode($arr) . ';';
?>
```

Will render like this:

```
var products = [ { 'id': 1, 'productLine': 'Vintage Cars' }, { 'id': 2, 'productLine': 'Ships' } ];
```

Comment: You should call JSON.parse on the string rather than just adding it in directly - it is much safer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to encode the data structure as JSON in PHP, and then call JSON.parse() on the resulting string client-side. You can use `json_encode` to encode the data and [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) to parse the string.

Be careful to escape the JSON string appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your script is ALMOST ok from what I can tell. However you've mispelled hiddenHash 5 lines from the bottom. If I just change hiddengeghash to hiddenhash it runs without errors in jsfiddle atleast. I took the liberty to add a document.write just to make sure it actually returns an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/2WBjJ/

I also changed the second i to i2 since they're used in the same loop