# How do you do an eval within the scope of a json?

Tags: javascript

I have a `json` in the form of `{ a:1, b:10, c:43 }` for example.

I wish to perform `eval( "(a+b-5)*c" )` but applying it to the `json`, not the place where the `json` and the formula is.

Attempted this, trying to utilize the scope, but wouldn't find `a`.

```
var z = { a:1, b:10, c:43, eval:eval };
console.log( z.eval( "a+b" ) );
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean... but if you mean what I think you do, there'll be no way but to unpack the JSON, do the array, and re-pack it.

Comment: what array are you talking about?

Comment: This: `{ a:1, b:10, c:43 }` array, object, same difference in this case... it'd look something like `result = (myJSON.a+myJSON.b-5)*myJSON.c)`

Comment: how would one "unpack" it?

Comment: Well, where does the JSON come from? Can you show some code?

Comment: In no way encouraging this, but: `var json = { a:1, b:10, c:43 }; with (json) { eval( "(a+b-5)*c" ) }`

Comment: This json is the sum of several jsons with all (maybe some missing) properties, on which I must apply a formula as a string and I can guarantee that all the variables in that formula exist in the json

Comment: @go-oleg I would accept your answer should you post it like that. It worked for my purposes. also I can add several evals within that `with`.

Comment: @Discipol: Looks like vkurchatkin has a very similar answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with` keyword, but please don't. Using `with` and `eval` is not recommended.

```
var z = { a:1, b:10, c:43 };
with(z) {
    console.log(eval('a+b'));
}
```

Here's some [more info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: then how do I scope inside the json without `with`?

Comment: You can use ```with``` if you like, the whole approach as it is, is not recommended. If I would need to do something like this, I'd go back and re-think what I want to achieve and if there's a better way to do it. Although I'm not saying I've never done messy things myself due to lack of time or interest. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
function expression (expr) {
    return new Function('obj', 'with (obj) return ' + expr);
}

console.log(expression('(a+b-5)*c')({ a:1, b:10, c:43 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dont use eval!**
USE JSON.parse

[JSON.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[JSON.parse vs. eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

```
var obj=JSON.parse(json);

alert((obj.a+obj.b-5)*obj.c)
```

Comment: the question is about parsing and evaluating an expression, not parsing json

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like:

```
var yourJSon = '{ "a":1, "b":10, "c":43 }'; 
//Your original JSon String (attention to the standard double quotes)

yourJSon = JSON.parse(yourJSon); 
//this will render your JSon string into a "real" object

var answer = eval("(yourJSon.a + yourJSon.b - 5) * yourJSon.c"); 
//And now you can do the eval, using the object's variable to define the scope of that object.
```