# javascript convert string to multi array array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an initial array (users) with multiple (string and numeric) arrays therein:

```
var users = [
['User: 10792 - Jack',45.7546,-117.807,2,'/res/smR11.gif'], ['User: 11248 - John',38.0867,131.976,3,'/res/smR08.gif']
];
```

I have a string of data from our server in the current form of:

```
newData = "['User: 18469 - Gary',-33.9399732539481,151.164383805489,3,'/res/markerw.gif'],['User: 10020 - Robert',40.6437563454472,-73.7593346140851,6,'/res/smR10.gif']";
```

I erase all existing data with users.length = 0;

I then need to insert the newData into the users array.

> NOTE: I can obviously modify the server data into any other format
>   that would be more suitable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: You give no enough information. What the language and techonlogy do you use? ASP.NET MVC / Ruby on rails, PHP, etc

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) would be more suitable. It then would be as as simple as `users = JSON.parse(newData)` (overwriting, not appending)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `newData` string looks *very* similar to the javascript above it. How about this...

```
users = eval('[' + newData + ']');
```

[*EDIT*]
As Bergi, rajeshkakawat and StephenJames pointed out, `eval` will work but is less secure.

See: [JSON.parse vs. eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

Comment: this would work, but use of eval is generally discouraged because it isn't that safe and is also sluggish, `JSON.parse` would be a more efficient and robust method.

Comment: @user2919549 Given it was actually Stephen's idea, maybe you could upvote one of his answers

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
     var users = JSON.parse(newData);
```