# json objects javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have no idea why this isn't displaying anything. I am trying to get the information in the var txt to generate dynamically in the html!

```
function byId (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var txt = '{"characters":[' +
'{"fullName":"John Doe","speci":"human male","occup":"Web Personality","cide":"Sleeper","descr":"blah","biog":"blarg","allia":"chaos good" },' +
'{"fullName":"Jane Doe","speci":human female",occup":"Movie Producer","cide":"Citric","descr":"bluh","biog":"blurg","allia":"neutral" },' +
'{"fullName":"Canter Doma","speci":alien male",occup":"Chef","cide":"Galv","descr":"bleh","biog":"blerg","allia":"evil" }]}';

var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");

byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[1].allia;
```

I have a test link here. http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/

Comment: Did you check for syntax errors? Try running through http://jsonlint.com/ and using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/2/ I fixed the syntax errors and it's still not working

Comment: JavaScript strings can't span multiple lines.  Make sure to check your JS console for errors.

Comment: Why are you trying to create JSON by hand, when there are perfectly fine functions to do this for you?

Comment: And there are also JSON parsing functions, why resort to `eval`?

Comment: In your example link in the question (http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/), you are missing some `"` in your JSON.

Comment: Thank you it was a spacing issue. Would you know a better way to write this as I am going to have 100s of characters   http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better if you weren't using eval.

You were missing quotes in occup and alien.

```
{
"characters":[
  {
     "fullName":"John Doe",
     "speci":"human male",
     "occup":"Web Personality",
     "cide":"Sleeper",
     "descr":"blah",
     "biog":"blarg",
     "allia":"chaos good"
  },
  {
     "fullName":"Jane Doe",
     "speci":"human female",
     occup":"Movie Producer",
     "cide":"Citric",
     "descr":"bluh",
     "biog":"blurg",
     "allia":"neutral"
  },
  {
     "fullName":"Canter Doma",
     "speci": "alien male",
     "occup":"Chef",
     "cide":"Galv",
     "descr":"bleh",
     "biog":"blerg",
     "allia":"evil"
  }
]}
```

Comment: Hmmm this is all very helpful. I do know really know best practices. I just find a sample online and run with it. Last 2 things Im trying to escape out to add an image into my array but it is breaking the array also. How do I write this so that it spits out all of the characters onto the page at once. I am learning and I do not know what to call everything just yet. http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/1/

Comment: You're trying to run before you can walk. Read a good JS book like "Javascript: The Good Parts" before starting on a project like this. Also consider using a library like JQuery, for cleaner HTML handling code.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

- Your JSON is not correctly formatted. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify syntax.
- JavaScript strings cannot span multiple lines.
- Use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval).

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/4/

Answer (score 1):

1. Just a couple of double quotes missing.
2. This part: `var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");` is not necessary I set it like
   this `var obj = txt;` for quickness.

Take a look to your code:

See your code now: http://jsfiddle.net/KLer3/6/

Answer (score 0):

There are missing quotes in your JSON. For example:

```
"speci":"human female",occup": "Movie Producer",
```

... is missing the opening quote for "occup" (and there are more, similar errors).

Fix these and your code works.

However, it's not good practice to use `eval()` to parse JSON, since it allows injection of code other than data structure assignment.

Use `JSON.parse()` instead:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
```

I assume you are writing JSON strings by hand as a way to experiment. Don't do this in real code. Use JSON.stringify(), or its equivalent on the server-side language.

If you really want your data inline with your code, you don't need JSON at all - just declare it in-place:

```
var obj = { characters: [
   {"fullName":"John Doe","speci":"human male", ... },
   {"fullName":"Jane Doe","speci":human female", ... },
   ...
]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors with missing quotation marks `"` - Make sure the code is written correctly before assuming you did something wrong... Otherwise seems like it should work...

Comment: Yes. Yes! Thank you all This is exactly what I had in mind. Any idea how I can make my character array spit out all of the data on the page at once. Like if I had 30 different characters and wanted them all to display. http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/

Answer (score 0):

Your string should look like this:

```
var txt='{'
+    '"characters": ['
+        '{'
+            '"fullName": "John Doe",'
+            '"speci": "human male",'
+            '"occup": "Web Personality",'
+            '"cide": "Sleeper",'
+            '"descr": "blah",'
+            '"biog": "blarg",'
+            '"allia": "chaos good"'
+        '},'
+        '{'
+            '"fullName": "Jane Doe",'
+            '"speci": "humanfemale",'
+            '"occup": "Movie Producer",'
+            '"cide": "Citric",'
+            '"descr": "bluh",'
+            '"biog": "blurg",'
+            '"allia": "neutral"'
+        '},'
+        '{'
+            '"fullName": "Canter Doma",'
+            '"speci": "alienmale",'
+            '"occup": "Chef",'
+            '"cide": "Galv",'
+            '"descr": "bleh",'
+            '"biog": "blerg",'
+            '"allia": "evil"'
+        '}'
+    ']'
+'}';
```

But as noted in the comments, doing this parsing by hand isn't the best practice.