# Rendering Column Dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I have DataTable loaded dynamically, all columns are coming from Database in JSON format  which aoColumns required.

I can render any column like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
{
    "sName": "I_CPN",
    "fnRender": function (oObj) 
    {
        return a button
    }
}]
```

Where `sName` is my Column name, this is static, I can get above content for `aoColumns` dynamically from C# code in JSON format. My problem is I am not able to put `fnRender` in JSON object.

How can I get `fnRender` so that I can render my Column as button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format can not carry function objects. Just some limited set of plain datatypes (see http://www.json.org) and everything else that can be serialized into string and deserialized back.

So you might transfer the function as string and then use `eval` on the JavaScript front-end to turn it back to code. See e.g. [JSON.parse vs. eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval) for examples of how to use `eval`.

Although this is possible it somehow breaks the original JSON as simple data container design.

You can also write some kind of generic `fnRender` function that will for instance take the column name and find corresponding button element using the [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) function.

Your example code is to small to provide better answer (in order to generalize we must have at least 2 examples :)

Comment: Hello xmojmr, You are correct, we cannot pass function with JSON object as this is serialized into string. also eval() is not good to use. So I followed different approach, I have generated java-script as string in C# portion and dump it to view when my dynamic table require script. As part of the script is dynamic so I did it C# side where I can easily interact with database.