# Google charts - use string as data (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I am using google charts and the code to generate a chart is indicated as:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 4],
    ['Olives', 3],
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2],         
]);
```

I am using php and I get result from a web service with ajax as string. For example I get a result as:

```
"[['Mushrooms', 3],['Onions', 4],['Olives', 3],['Zucchini', 1],['Pepperoni', 2],]"
```

I am trying to put this result in data.addRows(); for eg.

```
data.addRows(result);
```

However, it fails and generates no result. How can I append these data to the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse to parse the string as JSON. Eval [should be avoided if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval) because it is more vulnerable to attacks.

```
var json = JSON.parse(result);
data.addRows(json);
```