# Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string

```
str = "{'a':1}";
JSON.parse(str);
VM514:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(…)
```

How can I parse the above string (str) into a JSON object ?

This seems like a simple parsing. It's not working though.

Comment: Single quotes are not correctly formatted json, so if you're receiving something like that, you'd probably need to use str.replace() and replace single qoutes with " before trying to parse it

Comment: You should anyway always try to use single quotes for strings in javascript. `var str = "bad example";` is not good practice, better do the following: `var str = 'good example';` => like this you won't have any problems with JSON and you wont have any problems with HTML either. :)

Comment: @ReeCube That seems little more than an opinion--there's no problem with HTML anyway, it accepts both. For JSON, why create it with strings anyway? I don't actually recall the last time I built JSON out of anything other than an object.

Comment: the whole web development is a mess. and enforce strict rule for no discerning reason seems stupid. IMO.. where is good reason to allow swapping single and double quote at will.. it works in python. and it should work in json. for example try to write hardcoded json in your code and you get bunch of escaped quotes.. so many that you can hardly read which defies purpose of json as a clean text format.. the dev community sways from one extreme to another without hanging on a reasonable ground.

Comment: @BoppityBop JavaScript has at least three different ways of writing string literals: `"double quotes"`, `'single quotes'` and `\`back ticks\``. JSON however is distinct from JavaScript and has it's own [formal specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) which only permits the use of double quotes for property names and string values.

Comment: @ReeCube _"You should anyway always try to use single quotes for strings in javascript"_ Where did you get this from? single vs double quotes is simply preference and coding style.

Comment: @phuzi I learned a lot since 2016 and I agree with you on the "preference and coding style" part. 

Back then I spent a lot of time on PHP. There double quotes do something different than single quotes. So I trained myself to use single quotes.

In my years of working as a developer I faced a lot of issues. Own issues and issues of colleagues. My experience showed that some of these issues come from using wrong quotes (like this question proves).

Comment: Mostly I would use `back ticks` today. Sometimes I use single quotes. I still never use double quotes (except for html since there it is the "default"). Also I agree with Dave Newton: I can not remember the last time I wrote actual JSON outside of a `.json` file. So better would be to avoid hardcoded JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: 8 years, crazy how the time goes... thank you for reviving this discussion @phuzi

Answer (score 120):

The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes, nor will the parser.

If you have a simple case with no escaped single quotes in your strings (which would normally be impossible, but this isn't JSON), you can simple `str.replace(/'/g, '"')` and you should end up with valid JSON.

Comment: Your answer will tamper with data. A good answer would change the structure and not the data inside the data structure.

Comment: @ssube, global replacing single quotes with double ones is the first that comes to the mind and is a slipshod method, because it can destroy the dictionary values. E.g. `'title': "Mama's Friend"` will become  `"title": "Mama"s Friend"`, which is of course invalid! I should downvote your reply but I am against downvoting. This comment is worth much more.

Comment: Hi @Apostolos I agree with you and I now face the same issue. Were you able to find a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I found a solution @Selvam, but it's a long time ago but I can't remember what was it since I very rarely use JSON stuff these days. Sorry! :(

Comment: No problem. Thanks for responding @Apostolos

Comment: what if a string is - `{a:A}`? How can we parse this?

Answer (score 54):

I know it's an old post, but you can use [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) for this purpose.

```
<script src="json5.js"></script>
<script>JSON.stringify(JSON5.parse('{a:1}'))</script>
```

Comment: Upvoted because above solutions will fail with something like:

`{'section': "24'"}`

which becomes:

`{"section": "24""}`

and won't parse.

Comment: Perfect solution. Was trying to scrape a JSON string from html's script tag, which contains linebreaks and empty spaces. Saved my day!

Comment: For me this worked
`<script>JSON.stringify(some_jsonString)</script>`

Comment: How would you implement this? I'm trying to read the file in R using jsonlite package.

Comment: It is good to know json5 available, just learned it here :)

Answer (score 22):

If you are sure your JSON is safely under your control (not user input) then you can simply evaluate the JSON. Eval accepts all quote types as well as unquoted property names.

```
var str = "{'a':1}";
var myObject = (0, eval)('(' + str + ')');
```

The extra parentheses are required due to how the eval parser works.
Eval is not evil when it is used on data you have control over.
For more on the difference between JSON.parse and eval() see [JSON.parse vs. eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval)

Comment: Even if you think eval is not evil in this case, JSON.parse is always faster: https://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-eval/3

Comment: @Arkanoid The benchmark you linked to does not apply to this case as it uses only valid JSON (due to JSON.stringify)

Comment: Good points, so you can get the js object that corresponds to your data

Answer (score 9):

```
var str =  "{'a':1}";
str = str.replace(/'/g, '"')
obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: this will modify the data as well. `{'a':"A'A"}` will become `{"a":"A"A"}`

Answer (score 8):

Using single quotes for keys are not allowed in JSON. You need to use double quotes.

For your use-case perhaps this would be the easiest solution:

```
str = '{"a":1}';
```

[Source](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Double_Quotes):

> If a property requires quotes, double quotes must be used. All
>   property names must be surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 7):

```
// regex uses look-forwards and look-behinds to select only single-quotes that should be selected
const regex = /('(?=(,\s*')))|('(?=:))|((?<=([:,]\s*))')|((?<={)')|('(?=}))/g;
str = str.replace(regex, '"');
str = JSON.parse(str);
```

The other answers simply do not work in enough cases. Such as the above cited case: `"title": "Mama's Friend"`, it naively will convert the apostrophe unless you use regex. JSON5 will want the removal of single quotes, introducing a similar problem.

Warning: although I believe this is compatible with all situations that will reasonably come up, and works much more often than other answers, it can still break in theory.

Comment: This fails on the first quote after a newline in a new object. Add in a `{` with the `[:,]` to ensure it catches it: `/('(?=(,\s*')))|('(?=:))|((?<=([{:,]\s*))')|((?<={)')|('(?=}))/g`

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("result");

var str = "{'a':1}";
  str = str.replace(/\'/g, '"');
  var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
  console.log(parsed);
  div.innerText = parsed.a;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you just get python data, it looks a little bit like json but it is not. If you know that it is pure python data, then you can eval these data with python and convert it to json like this:

```bash
echo "{'a':1}" | /usr/bin/python3 -c "import json;print(json.dumps(eval(input())))"
```

Output:

```
{"a": 1}
```

this is good json.

if you are in javascript, then you could use `JSON.stringify` like this:

```js
data = {'id': 74,'parentId': null};
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Output:

```
> '{"id":74,"parentId":null}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an escape for your double quotes like the following:

```js
str = "{\"a\":1}";
JSON.parse(str);
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party - but this is what helped me (Python)

Import Json - Python has the built-in module json, which allows us to work with JSON data.

```
import json
```

Print the JSON data with indentation

```
print(json.dumps(str_json_data, indent=4))
```

Write the JSON data in a file

```
with open("test.json", "w") as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(str_json_data, indent=4))
```

Answer (score -4):

If you assume that the single-quoted values are going to be displayed, then instead of this:

```
str = str.replace(/\'/g, '"');
```

you can keep your display of the single-quote by using this:

```
str = str.replace(/\'/g, '\&apos;\');
```

which is the HTML equivalent of the `single quote`.

Answer (score -14):

```
json = ( new Function("return " + jsonString) )();
```

Comment: Please explain your answers

Comment: Guys, don't ever do this. This is super unsafe

Comment: The principal of using `Function` instead of eval is sound, but everything else is wrong. It should be `var json = Function("'use strict';return " + jsonString)()`

Comment: Don't get the comments here. This COULD be unsafe, not unsafe in any implementation, same as many APIS!.
It's funny to me that this answer got 10+ downvotes while the answer with 'eval' got 15+ vote ups when THEY ARE "UNSAFE" IN EXACTLY THE SAME WAY.
When there is no chance for user input to be evaluated, there is NO RISK AT ALL!
Using Function constructor for instead of 'eval', is perfectly fine, and much more elegant to do.

Comment: How is the function constructor more elegant than eval? They do pretty much the same thing except one is obfuscated and the other isn't. This answer could at least add a few words of caution, considering if `jsonString` is untrusted, your client can execute arbitrary code. Seems reasonable to act with some discretion or at least show a simple warning when you're giving someone the code equivalent of a box of TNT.