# list of list seen in string type in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
["[{'month': 'March', 'amount': 950}, {'month': 'Apr…'amount': 390}, {'month': 'July', 'amount': 450}]"]
```

how to get this output?

```js
[{'month': 'March', 'amount': 950}, {'month': 'Apr…'amount': 390}, {'month': 'July', 'amount': 450}]
```

how to solve it?

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow, but, if I understand correctly, you have an array with a string representation of an array of objects (`['[obj1, obj2...]']`). If you want to get the actual array of objects, you should parse the string with `JSON.parse`:
`JSON.parse(array[0])`

Comment: You should explain better the request and add the code portion that generate the output

Comment: How did you obtain that string? It is not JSON and you would have to parse it by yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes) and [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes on key and keyvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928599)

Comment: JSON data         [
    {
        "data": "[{'month': 'March', 'amount': 950}, {'month': 'April', 'amount': 390}, {'month': 'July', 'amount': 450}]",
        "name": "rakesh",
        "year": "2019"
    },....]

Comment: then use str[0].data.replace(...   in my answer. @ADITHYANPS

Comment: @ADITHYANPS The nested string is not JSON. JSON only supports double quotes.

Comment: @str it is a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var original = ["[{'month': 'March', 'amount': 950}, {'month': 'Apr…','amount': 390}, {'month': 'July', 'amount': 450}]"]

var answer = JSON.parse((original[0].replace(/'/g, '"')));

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: then the data type will changed to string .i want array type

Answer (score 2):

your data is not a valid stringified JSON but still if you need to parse in into an array

```js
var str = ["[{'month': 'March', 'amount': 950}, {'month': 'Apr', 'amount': 390}, {'month': 'July', 'amount': 450}]"]

var array = JSON.parse((str[0].replace(/'/g, '"')));

console.log(Array.isArray(array));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Input is not 100% ok... If you have follow string:

```
'[{"month":"March","amount":950},{"month":"Apr…","amount":390}, "month":"July","amount":450}]'
```

you can use:

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"month":"March","amount":950},{"month":"Apr…","amount":390},{"month":"July","amount":450}]')
```