# Loading GeoJSON into Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-marker

When I use GeoJSON inside the HTML it works, but when I try to load externally it doesn't.

My HTML file and GeoJSON file are in the same folder in site.

I try to open picture popups with markers.

Thanks a lot!

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'lalalalala';
var southWest = L.latLng(40.875557, 29.235992),
    northEast = L.latLng(41.277226, 28.749847),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.light', {
    maxBounds: bounds,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 11
});      

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  .loadURL('http://terkedilmisarabalar.mudurlugu.org/geojson/terkedilmisarabalar.geojson')
  .on('ready', function() {
    myLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      map.fitBounds(myLayer.getBounds());
      layer.bindPopup(layer.features.properties.name);
    });
  })
  .addTo(map);

myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
myLayer.on('onclick', function(e) {
    e.layer.openPopup();
});
myLayer.on('onrelease', function(e) {
    e.layer.closePopup();
});
```

Here is an example GeoJSON file:

```
{
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
    {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Acıbadem Cd. No:117",
    "description": "<img src=\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/DkEl65k9kZAtvPdf9HuE22aIAJKUKBDtiL0m5vZBRqn9nVsgcQIQYdi03gt5yhOKcrEvTQpctu_xnLVfhzzt6Tr3fGtsxuIJSqPrf7R9p-0faSL-YRxTzyn44B8KVB8\" height=\"200\" width=\"auto\" /><br><br>",
    "gx_media_links": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/fmIjm4ynkTWSkmzcOfoMCoVgnm6h9pQ8KINgHqhjx-ZNQMrT05NqsZo2Lv5d6FwFFakmqOzl_ruRKvu34jbC96U3nKaxlu0sul6W4qXU1ily4PNbLCQTsR2BGKOxervb"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      29.045881,
      41.005992,
      0
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36038483/2626313

Comment: Thank you! Yes it was the syntax.