# How to parse JSON strings with single quotes in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from an URL but it appears the data is in the wrong format:

```
song = {
'artist':'Tom Waits',
'song':'New Coat Of Paint',
'lyrics':'Let\'s put a new coat of paint on this lonesome old town\nSet \'em up, we\'ll be knockin\' em [...]',
'url':'http://lyrics.wikia.com/Tom_Waits:New_Coat_Of_Paint'
}
```

from this URL: [JSON URL](http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist=Tom%20Waits&song=new%20coat%20of%20paint&fmt=json)

Is there a way to modify the JSON data so it can be parsed correctly?

Comment: Don't repost questions. Once again, **this is not JSON**

Comment: There is a way around in for JAVA, there must be a way around it for Swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes

Comment: "There is a way around in for JAVA, there must be a way around it for Swift". This is like "Hey, I'm not respecting the rules, but can you still do something ?" There is no built-in iOS for that case, it's not valid JSON. You may find solutions maybe on GitHub or related ressources sites, but it will pass the message that's the a correct way for JSON, which is not. But as said in your previous question, you're were using wrong URL (that formatted it not as JSON).