# Can't convert JSON string to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert JSON string to javascript object, but unsuccessfully.

This is my code:

```
result = "{'image': 'https://google.com/16469374645-11-12-05-27-10-2017.jpg', 'sender': 'Test test123', 'text': 'Test 005', 'expiry': '2016-10-15 01:51:28', 'points': 650, 'color_from': '#8DBCC5', 'color_to': '#13717C'}";
result = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(result);
alert(result);
```

I have created a fiddle with a demo.
https://jsfiddle.net/030u9z9f/1/

It seems like my JSON is not properly formatted, but I am not sure how to adjust it.

Comment: JSON has a specific format ... strings (and key names) are enclosed in `"` not `'` - see [documentation](https://www.json.org/)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There **JSON** does not contain any single quote for there key and value description you have change all `'` to `"` for the same string. There all the Key and Value should be enquoted by `"` and a complete string of JSON must be enclosed with `'` for better string conversion.

The JSON standard requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes, nor will the parser.

If you have a simple case with no escaped single quotes in your strings (which would normally be impossible, but this isn't JSON), you can simple str.replace(/'/g, '"') and you should end up with valid JSON.
check ...

```
result = '{"image": "https://google.com/16469374645-11-12-05-27-10-2017.jpg", "sender": "Test test123", "text": "Test 005", "expiry": "2016-10-15 01:51:28", "points": 650, "color_from": "#8DBCC5", "color_to": "#13717C"}';
result = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(result);
alert(result);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/030u9z9f/2/)

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this JSON,

```
{
"image": "https://google.com/16469374645-11-12-05-27-10-2017.jpg",
"sender": "Test test123",
"text": "Test 005",
"expiry": "2016-10-15 01:51:28",
"points": 650,
"color_from": "#8DBCC5",
"color_to": "#13717C"
}
```

Comment: add some description to your answer.

Comment: technically, that's not JSON, that's an object - now, how to make that a string ...???