# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON

how to convert this string to object in javascript?

```
JSON.parse( "[{'dia': '1', 'valor': '0,00'}, {'dia': '2', 'valor': '0,00'}, {'dia': '3', 'valor': '0,00'}]" );
```

> VM85380:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position
>   0
>       at JSON.parse ()

Comment: JSON need double quotes for strings. Single quote the outside, double quote the inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON always needs to preceeded with single to double quotes, if you're parsing a String.

change your line to:

```
JSON.parse( '[{"dia": 1, "valor": "0,00"}, {"dia": 2, "valor": "0,00"}, {"dia": 3, "valor": "0,00"}]' );
```

PS: If you want to store your `valor` as a float, you should change its format from `0,00` to `0.00`