# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

[image: Error Message]

I'm getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string error, yet when I look at the source, as far as I can tell, it's correct. I can't see any missing commas or quotation marks. Any one have any tips?

(yes, I've searched to see if I can find the problem, but it always seems to be quotation marks and commas)

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code thats failing

Comment: invisible character?

Comment: I suppose StandardsData should be an array and from your picture it doesn't seem so ..

Comment: @MeesKluivers I suppose, this _is_ the failing code. This is no correct array declaration ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36038454/5711524 read this

Comment: Downvoted : code posted as image, we can't copy paste it.

Comment: @MeesKluivers OP's code is not JSON so that's unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a pair of square brackets to contain the entries

For example,

```
let StandardsData = [
    {
        // stuff
    },
    {
        // stuff
    },
    {
        // stuff
    },
]
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close between [ ] that array