# python: Unable to convert string to json

Tags: python, json

Although the following seems to be a valid json string, I am unable to `json.load` it.

```
In [33]:  mystr="{ 'username': 'Newman Test Executor', 'channel': '#someslackchannel' }"

In [34]: json.loads(mystr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-6f4efa0d20c6> in <module>()
----> 1 json.loads(mystr)

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    337             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    338             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 339         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    340     if cls is None:
    341         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    362 
    363         """
--> 364         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    365         end = _w(s, end).end()
    366         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    378         """
    379         try:
--> 380             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    381         except StopIteration:
    382             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: Rule#1: JSON strings should have double quoted property names.

Answer (score 2):

As both @Austin and @Arya mentioned above, you need to have double quotes in your JSON string to be valid. In your case, you could simply replace the single quote with a double quote:

```
import json
mystr="{ 'username': 'Newman Test Executor', 'channel': '#someslackchannel' }"
json.loads(mystr.replace('\'','"'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
mystr = '{ "username": "Newman Test Executor", "channel": "#someslackchannel" }'
my_dict = { "username": "Newman Test Executor", "channel": "#someslackchannel" }



print(json.loads(mystr))
print(json.dumps(my_dict))
```

output:

```
{u'username': u'Newman Test Executor', u'channel': u'#someslackchannel'}
{"username": "Newman Test Executor", "channel": "#someslackchannel"}
```

Single quotes outside, double quotes inside incase of strings.

If you have no control over the `json string` being passed to you, you can use `mystr.replace('\'', '"')` as mentioned by **Vasilis G.**

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes inside of the JSON string.

See [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

> The JSON standard requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes, nor will the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Followed what Arya commented and got the code to work. Answer can be found in another forum though..

```
import json
mystr='{ "username": "Newman Test Executor","channel": "#someslackchannel"}'

json.loads(mystr)
```