# Get the array in a string [javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to get the array in the string below:

```
"['Comedian', 'Actor']"
```

For example, for the above, I should get `['Comedian', 'Actor']`.

Already working using `eval()`. Is there any other way to get the desired result?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally i would suggest using a `JSON.parse` functionality to do so, however since this is not a valid json format due to single quotes instead of double quotes you could try to first replace those and only then parse

```js
const str = "['Comedian','Actor']";

console.log(JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"')));
```

or you could use JSON5

```js
const str = "['Comedian','Actor']";
console.log(JSON5.parse(str));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@^2.0.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```