# Converting array inside a string to an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a response which contains an array which is present inside string(`""`). What I need I just the array. How do I get rid of the quotes?

I tried `JSON.parse()`. It gave me error message

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

What I have is as follows:

```
email_id: "['abc@mail.com', 'cde@mail.com']"
```

What I need is as follows:

```
email_id: ['abc@mail.com', 'cde@mail.com']
```

This is a key which a part of a large response I am getting from backend in my angular 7 app.

Comment: Use JSON.parse(response.email_id) to parse only email_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below solution will work for your case provided the strings does not contain `/'`

```
var a = "['abc@mail.com', 'cde@mail.com', 'def@mail.com']";
a = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
var result = JSON.parse(a);
```

Considering its an email data, there's no possibility of having that escape character sequence

Answer (score 1):

You have to send in backend the format with double quotes instead of one quotes or in front just replace quotes `'` with double quotes " inside your array , otherwise the parse will fail ,

see below snippet :

```js
let json = {
  email_id:  "['abc@mail.com', 'cde@mail.com']"
}
json.email_id = json.email_id.replace(/'/g,"\"");
console.log(JSON.parse(json.email_id));
```