# Vue isse with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm new to VUE i have issue to convert dict to JSON in my Vue data

i have a paragraph with innerHTML `{'id': '1', 'name':'test'}`

i need to convert this string to object in my Vue.

I try:

```
const helloWorld = new Vue({

   el:'#helloVue',


   data: {
      dict:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('vuedata').innerHTML)),


   },


 delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],

})
```

but when i expect Vue data it show me a string, not an object.

Comment: Duplicate of [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Comment: The call to `JSON.stringify` is redundant as `innerHTML` returns a string and to have `JSON.parse` work properly you need to replace the single-quotes with double-quotes (for example using `str.replace(/'/g, '"')`).

Comment: Javascript doesn't have dict's, it has object's and Map's, please use to learn the proper terminology for the language so that you don't confuse others, thanks,  I could edit the question for you I suppose, but if you haven't edited a question before, here's your chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute that `dict` value directly in `data` but it's better to do it in `computed`, like so:

```
computed: {
  dict() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('vuedata').innerHTML))
  }
}
```

You can then use that value in template, like you would normally use `data` properties:

```
<div>{{dict}}</div>
```

Or use it in other computed / methods by specifying `this.`, example:

```
console.log(this.dict)
```

By the way, the `data` property should `return` the values, like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    dict1: ...,
    dict2: ...,
    ...
  }
}
```