# POST request returns 404 while GET doesn't

Tags: python, api, https, nagios

When I'm doing a GET request everything works fine but when I try a POST request, it returns 404.

I'm working on this API that interacts with Nagios :
https://github.com/EyesOfNetworkCommunity/eonapi

Here's my python GET resquest :

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://device/eonapi/getAuthenticationStatus?username=test&apiKey=49fd4f56qs4dfs2sdf4')

print(r.json())
print(r.status_code)
```

And the result :

```
{'api_version': '2.4.2', 'http_code': '200 OK', 'status': 'authorized'}
200
```

The POST request when I'm trying to get information about a monitored host :

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://device/eonapi/getHost?username=test&apiKey=49fd4f56qs4dfs2sdf4', data = {'hostName':'test1'})

print(r.status_code)
```

Result :

```
404
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried these requests with PHP and cURL but I still get the same results.

Comment: Use `'Content-Type': "application/json"` in the headers and use double quotes for your JSON data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038497/12409170

Comment: I tried but unfortunately still get 404 
`import requests

host = {
    "hostName":"test1"
}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('https://device/eonapi/getHost?username=test&apiKey=49fd4f56qs4dfs2sdf4', data=host, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
`

Answer (score -2):

You probably have to use a get request because the url says "getHost" and your trying to get data. Have you tried using get on that url?

Comment: The documentation of eonapi states, that this must be a post request.

Comment: Well yes I'm trying to get the name of the host but it requires a POST request. You post the hostname and you get information. It is written in the documentation. Although I did try with GET and I still got 404