# Javascript - Parse a stringified arrays of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have a string like so :

```
a= "['url1','url2','url3']"
```

coming from the server I want to convert it to array like :

```
arr = ["url1","url2","url3"]
```

but `JSON.parse` does not seems to be working and gives following error:

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In JSON, strings must be represented with double quotes. Instead of trying to find a hacky workaround, can't you fix the server to make it send valid JSON?

Comment: I think you mistyped, but surely you meant `JSON.parse` rather than `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: So what will be the valid json format for this array?

Comment: `"[\"url1\",\"url2\",\"url3\"]"` would be valid. But you should never ever ever ever try to build a JSON string yourself. Always use the built-in tools, like `json_encode` in PHP, or `JSON.stringify` in JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the single quotes with double quotes. An easy way to achieve this can be by replacing them with escaped quotes like this:

```
let validJSON = a.replace(/'/g, "\"")

JSON.parse(validJSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string needs to be in single quotes for JSON.parse to work in this example, also string representation in json uses double quotes as per standard.

```js
JSON.parse('["url1","url2","url3"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
a = "['url1','url2','url3']"
urls = a.split(',')
arr = urls.map(url => url.replace(/'|\[|\]/g, ''))

console.log(arr) // ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1frh8ys/