# Convert string "object" to object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I need to convert `inlineScriptsTexts` to object, because I need getting values from this. But I don't know, how to parse this string to object. `[JSON.parse][1]` does not work as expected. Is there some solution, which convert this string to object (like on image)?

[image: img]

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let objExist = false;
  let inlineScripts = document.body;
  let inlineScriptsBlocks = Array.from(inlineScripts.getElementsByTagName('script'));
  inlineScriptsBlocks.forEach(scriptBlock => {
    let inlineScriptsTexts = scriptBlock.innerText;
    if (inlineScriptsTexts.includes('zvkDL')) {
      objExist = true;
      console.log(inlineScriptsTexts);
    }
  });

  //console.log(objExist);
}
```

```
zvkDL = {
            'language' : 'cs',
            'currency' : 'czk',
            'event': 'akurva',
            'ecommerce': {
                'purchase': {
                    'actionField': {
                        'id': 555,
                        'revenue': 535535,
                        'shipping': 3535,
                    }
                }
            },
            'eventCallback': function() {
                setGTMcookie( 555 ); // Jak se bude callback jmenovat nechám na vás. Jen to musí být srozumitelné. Pozor na scope JS callbacku.
            },
            'eventTimeout' : 2000,
            'eventCookie': { 'name': 'dasd', 'expires': 'asdsadd', 'value': 'funguje to', }
        };
```

Comment: Hi ! Is zvkDL an example for inlineScriptsTexts ?

Comment: Can you click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]?

Comment: It would help clarify things if you could provide an example of actual string contents, and what you want that string parsed to.

Comment: Do you want to parse a relaxed JSON string with single quote around keys? Something like this: [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454)

Comment: Yes @lndgalante

Comment: zvkDL is example from HTML @jarmod

Comment: That's not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to help

```
if (inlineScriptsTexts.includes('zvkDL '+'=')) {
  const str = inlineScriptsTexts.trim()
   .replace('zvkDL '+'=',"")
   .replace(/'/g,'"')
   .replace(/\/\/.*?\n/g,"")
   .replace(/\};/g,"}")
  console.log(str)
  console.log(JSON.parse(str));
}
```

But the function is a BIG problem

```js
// the reason it won't work:
// this is as good as a representation of the object as can be made

const obj =  {
    "language": "cs",
    "currency": "czk",
    "event": "akurva",
    "ecommerce": {
      "purchase": {
        "actionField": {
          "id": 555,
          "revenue": 535535,
          "shipping": 3535,
        }
      }
    },
    "eventCallback": function() { setGTMcookie(555); }, // this will NOT be seen by JSON

    "eventTimeout": 2000,
    "eventCookie": {
      "name": "dasd",
      "expires": "asdsadd",
      "value": "funguje to",
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

/*


window.onload = function() {
  let objExist = false;
  let inlineScripts = document.body;
  let inlineScriptsBlocks = Array.from(inlineScripts.getElementsByTagName('script'));
  inlineScriptsBlocks.forEach(scriptBlock => {
    let inlineScriptsTexts = scriptBlock.innerText;
    if (inlineScriptsTexts.includes('zvkDL '+'=')) {
      const str = inlineScriptsTexts.trim().replace('zvkDL '+'=',"").replace(/'/g,'"').replace(/\/\/.*?\n/g,"").replace(/\};/g,"}")
      console.log(str)
      console.log(JSON.parse(str));
    }
  });
}*/
```

```html
<script>
  zvkDL = {
    'language': 'cs',
    'currency': 'czk',
    'event': 'akurva',
    'ecommerce': {
      'purchase': {
        'actionField': {
          'id': 555,
          'revenue': 535535,
          'shipping': 3535,
        }
      }
    },
    'eventCallback': function() {
      setGTMcookie(555); // Jak se bude callback jmenovat nechám na vás. Jen to musí být srozumitelné. Pozor na scope JS callbacku.
    },
    'eventTimeout': 2000,
    'eventCookie': {
      'name': 'dasd',
      'expires': 'asdsadd',
      'value': 'funguje to',
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method provided in JavaScript is `eval` - used to execute a string containing JavaScript source code.

JSON strings used to serialize a restricted set of data objects using text in "JavaScript Object Notation" can't be used in this case because JSON does not support serializing function objects.

There are two major alternatives to `eval`:

1. Convert the text into a function by calling the global `Function` constructor, or
2. Writing the text to a file on the server and downloading the file to a browser using `<script>` tags.

Calling `eval` or `Function` to execute code has a bad reputation and can be restricted in some code environments.

Before taking any of these approaches I would analyze the problem precisely: where is the string coming from, would it be better to solve the problem further up the source chain by creating a script in the first place, would cloning an existing source object without serializing it first be possible etc.

Also a note of caution if it applies: the `textContent` of an HTMLScriptElement can only be used to access the code if the element contains inline code. `textContent` will not return the code content of a downloaded script file.