# Javascript Trying to parse string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string-parsing

I am having a variable which stores a string like this

`var colorArr="['#3f67c5', '#cb4728', '#f19d39', '#459331', '#984830', '#8C2094']"`

I am trying to convert this string into an array by

`var result = JSON.parse(colorArr)`

But I keep on getting the following error
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Is there a way by which I can convert this string into a proper array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your string is not a valid JSON. You must use double quotes in JSON: `var colorArr = '["#3f67c5", "#cb4728", ...]'`.

Comment: @kaveh Thanks...yup it worked

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes JSON standard requires double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes and put double quotes inside of it

```js
var colorArr= '["#3f67c5", "#cb4728", "#f19d39", "#459331", "#984830", "#8C2094"]';

var result = JSON.parse(colorArr)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace and split.

```js
let colorArr="['#3f67c5', '#cb4728', '#f19d39', '#459331', '#984830', '#8C2094']";
let myArray = colorArr.replace(/'/g,'"')
console.log(JSON.parse(myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var colorArr='["#3f67c5", "#cb4728", "#f19d39", "#459331", "#984830", "#8C2094"]';
JSON.parse(colorArr)
```