# Unexpected token I in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code:

```
<script>
try {
    var ob = JSON.parse("{ ID: 1, 'Code':'001', 'Name':'john', 'HasParent':false, 'HasGrandParent':false, 'IsAgent':False }");
    document.write(ob.Name);
}
catch(err) {
    document.write(err);
}
</script>
```

Here is the error message:

```
Unexpected token I in JSON at position 2
```

I have no idea what's happening. What's wrong here?

==================

Thanks for the answer from JayTheKay below.

The problems and fixes are:

1. use double quote for string
2. boolean value is lower case, so "False" is wrong, "false" is correct
3. this first key name `ID` is not wrapped with double quote

Comment: JSON doesn't support single quotes as keys.

Comment: also `False` should be `false`

Comment: @TiiJ7 yupe, I just found out this... :) thanks for tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON properties may not be enclosed in single quotes, you have to use double quotes. Take a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038497/891279

Your first property is not enclosed in quotes at all. This probably causes the error.

Comment: When you find a similar question, please flag it as a duplicate instead of posting an answer with a link to the question. Under the question, flag -> duplicate -> paste the URL in the box.

Comment: @adiga Actually, I was totally initially have no idea this has relation with the single quote or double quote. So, when I search the result in google, due to I didn't search for "single quote" in google search or stackoverflow search, I only search for the error message, and thus non related search result came out :) but nonetheless, thanks for you guys time in helping me :)

Comment: @adiga look at the tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_json.asp It showed the example in double quote, but it didn't mention it must use double quote and I thought it works the same as HTML tag handles double quote and single quote. as javascript also accept double quote and single quote as string, that's why I was confused initially :)

Comment: @mjb your question is valid. My comment was for JayTheKay on how to flag from next time onwards if they find a duplicate.

Comment: @mjb also, please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) instead of w3schools. Some of the stuff on w3schools is outdated and wrong ([Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478))