# Extract the array represented as a string

Tags: javascript

i have a string as below and i would like to extract the array between the quotes.

```js
mystring = "['str1','str2']"
```

I tried it with eval and i do not want to use eval in my code. is there any other neat way to do this ?

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse`

Comment: @mousetail the string is sadly not valid JSON.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sad

Comment: May use combination of slice and split

Comment: Yes. this is not a valid JSON and i dont want to use eval either.

Comment: @boredbear153 is the data in the string always an array of strings?

Comment: See [Parsing string as JSON with single quotes?](/q/36038454/4642212).

Comment: @evolutionxbox sometimes it can be integers as well. like "[5,6]"

Comment: @SebastianSimon This is working.. Replace the single quote into double quotes and then parsing it.. thank you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it does. and thank you.

Comment: #@SebastianSimon Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseString(string) {
  return string
    .split(",")
    .map((str) => str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replaceAll("'", ""));
}
```

This assumes none of array indexes includes character ",".

Comment: this works as expected. i will also get the input as "[5,6]". In this case, the expected output is  [5,6]. However, with the above function it is ["5","6"]. Do i have to transform it again checking if each element is a number or string ?

Comment: @boredbear153 Why not simply request valid JSON instead? Either use JSON or build your own custom parser.

Comment: @boredbear153, Yes, I think you need to do that. Also, I think there are quite a few other things that should be considered. Will be a complicated function in the end.

Comment: @Erfan Yes. i m considering the answer from the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes

Comment: @SebastianSimon I will request to provide valid JSOn. Not sure if it is possible in this case,  based on the outcome, i need to decide my next step.