# Group JSON in order for it to be more readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have this file (`MYFILE.txt`) that is the output of a list of lists with dictionaries inside:

```
[{'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.99999213, 'word': 'DNA', 'start': 0, 'end': 3}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.9768174, 'word': 'loop', 'start': 4, 'end': 8}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.9039155, 'word': 'ing,', 'start': 8, 'end': 12}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.99962616, 'word': 'in', 'start': 13, 'end': 15}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.9949911, 'word': 'which a protein or protein complex interacts simultaneously', 'start': 16, 'end': 75}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.59057885, 'word': 'with', 'start': 76, 'end': 80}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.9983214, 'word': 'two separated sites on a DNA molecule, is a recurring theme', 'start': 81, 'end': 140}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.9998679, 'word': 'in', 'start': 141, 'end': 143}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.9997542, 'word': 'transcription', 'start': 144, 'end': 157}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.7964442, 'word': 'regula', 'start': 158, 'end': 164}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.99982435, 'word': 'tion [', 'start': 164, 'end': 170}]
```

I want to group the "literal" in order to get the text only, and leave the metaphoric as it is. I tried with this code below but it says `string indices must be integers`, and I also think that I could make it HTML and color it to visualize better the result, but I'm sure there's a quicker solution.

```
with open(r'MYFILE.txt', 'r') as res:
  texty = res.read()
  for group in texty[::-1]:
      ent = group["entity_group"]
      if ent != 'literal': 
      text2 = replace_at(ent, group['end'], group['end'], text)
print(text2)
```

Comment: What are the contents of 'MYFILE.txt'?

Comment: What do you expect to get in the end?

Comment: The content is what I put before, the json

Comment: I expect to get sth like "hello how are you {entoty group metaphoric etc.} I'm fine", so the literal ones are text and the rest stays the same

Comment: @Idkwhatywantmed there is no JSON in your q. the first snippet is a python dictionary, but JSON standards require double quotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038454/parsing-string-as-json-with-single-quotes ...also, `.read()` (generally) returns a string and if it *was* json, you'd need [`json.loads`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads/) to parse it into a python object

Answer (score 0):

> but it says `string indices must be integers`

`texty` is a string [**not a list** of dictionaries as you seem to be expecting] because that's what *`.read()`* returns (when you `open` with `mode='r'`); so when you iterate through it with *`for group in texty...`*, each `group` is a single-character string [and not a dictionary], and that's why the error is being raised [I assume] at *`ent = group["entity_group"]`*.

---

Reluctant suggestion: Try adding a line with **`exec(f'texty = {texty.strip()}')`** before *`for group...`*.

But this is NOT a good way to save data. Please look into [json](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) and [pickle](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-pickle-to-save-objects-2813661). [I prefer json as it's not specific to python.]

---

---

As for

> I also think that I could make it HTML and color it to visualize better the result, but I'm sure there's a quicker solution

I'm afraid there isn't enough code nor context to fully understand what you mean here. Including the definition of `replace_at` as well as a sample set of `text` and [desired] `text2` values might help.