# Parse String Without using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, string-parsing

Good day. I have an array that needs to be parsed in a JSON format. However, the browser object does not support JSON calls...unfortunately. Is there a way to brute force the script into a JSON parse without explicitly calling it?

Essentially, I am calling data from a SQL tbl and need to retrieve the data in order to make a table. I need the array parsed in order to make a html table into rows and columns.

Any help is most appreciated.

Current Array No Parsing

```
"[["0","Accumulation is at 100% Full","78"],["0","Accumulation is at 50% Full","77"],["1","Accumulation Time Purge Warning","79"]]"
```

Desired Array with Parsing

```
  0:Array(3)
    0:"0"
    1:"Accumulation is at 100% Full"
    2:"78"
    length:3
    __proto__:Array(0)
  1:Array(3)
    0:"0"
    1:"Accumulation is at 50% Full"
    2:"77"
    length:3
    __proto__:Array(0)
  2:Array(3)
    0:"1"
    1:"Accumulation Time Purge Warning"
    2:"79"
    length:3
    __proto__:Array(0)
```

Comment: Use `$.parseJSON()`, it should provide a polyfill for browsers that don't support `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @ochi There are quotes around it, so it's a JSON string for a 2D array.

Comment: What browser are you using that doesn't support `JSON.parse()`? MDN says that it's compatible with IE8.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose

Comment: if you can't use JSON.parse can you use eval? If so check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval

Comment: `myArr = eval(yourString);`  Only use values of yourString that you have created carefully yourself.

Comment: @Barmar $.parseJSON() works, thanks.... I am using a Wonderware application which is a SCADA software that has an internal web browser object which says its an IE 11.096. It should have read JSON.parse, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$.parseJSON()`. If the browser doesn't support `JSON.parse()`, it provides a polyfill.

Make sure you're using jQuery 1.11 or higher. Earlier versions of jQuery used code equivalent to `eval()` for this polyfill, so it was dangerous. jQuery 1.11 has better validation of the input.